# Swift3: Using Two Arrays to populate grouped Table

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, struct

I currently have two populated arrays using a custom struct.

```
struct Group {
    var id: String
    var type: String
    var desc: String
    var name: String

    init() {
        id = ""
        type = ""
        desc = ""
        name = ""
    }
}
```

Data gets appended to:

```
var clientArray: [Group] = []
var departmentArray: [Group] = []
```

I essentially want to join them together to have the format something like [[clientArray], [departmentArray]] so I can use "section" and populate two different groups on a table with the respective arrays.

So far I've tried the following, but I get the error "fatal error: index out of range".

```
var masterArray = [[Group]]()
//Then further down the page...
 self.masterArray[0] = self.clientArray
 self.masterArray[1] = self.departmentArray
```

How can I get this to work? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write:

```
var masterArray = [self.clientArray, self.departmentArray]
```

Otherwise use `append:`. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) state:

> You can’t use subscript syntax to append a new item to the end of an
>   array.

Comment: Can't believe how simple that was!